# Call service from BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying a very simple service that needs to open upon OnReceive in BroadReceiver.

I have set an alarm and the alarm triggers the broadcastReceiver is opened OnReceive is called but I am not able to open the service from there. I don't get any log in service.

I hope we can call the service from BroadcastReceiver.

Here is the code:

```
public class AlarmABroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Context mContext;
    private localDB localdb;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Alarm_StaticWakeLock.lockOn(context);
        mContext = context;

        localdb = new localDB(context);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 12);
        long sdl = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        if (localdb.getAlarmCount() == 0)
        {
            Log.e("milli", "0= " + sdl);
            localdb.setaAlarm(String.valueOf(sdl));
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("milli", ">0= " + sdl);
            localdb.updateaAlarm(String.valueOf(sdl));
        }


        Intent service = new Intent(context, OpenService.class);
        context.startService(service);

        A_Util.setalarm(context);
    }
}
```

All the log that I have in this broadcastReceiver is coming... but doesn't openService.class

The same service class is opened in different activity class. So Manifest is not an issue.

Comment: Have you write log in Service?

Comment: @Amy: Yep. log is coming fine when I open the service from activity.

Comment: Try to shift you startService code to Beginning of onReceive Method.

Comment: @Amy: trying.. but does it make a difference?

Comment: You can print something inside Service class startService() method. Hence, you will get to know is it going into Service class or not?

Comment: r u using same class name code in activity, as i see classname to be wrong it should be word first letter caps i.e. OpenService and not openService

Comment: @VVB yes. I have logged and also given toast.

Comment: @Rejen Raiyarela: that was a typo mistake here..

Comment: It means your service gets started however code inside that there is something goes wrong

Comment: Where do you log in the service?